# Auto generate ID with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have this repository

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) var id: Long,
    @Column var count: Int = 1,
    @Column var added: Boolean = false,
    @Column var startDate: Date,
    @Column var endDate: Date,
)

interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Number> {}
```

and this service

```
@Service
class FooService@Autowired constructor(
    val fooRepository: FooRepository 
) {
    fun addWhatever(data: ...): Boolean {
        val foo = Foo(
            count = data.count,
            added = data.added,
            startDate = data.startDate,
            endDate = data.endDate
        )

        return ...
    }
}
```

Now I am getting

> No value passed for parameter 'id'

I wnat the `id` to be generated automatically, that is why I am not passing any `id` in the service....

Answer (score 0):

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) var id: Long` needs a default value, something like

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) var id: Long = 0`, because the compiler does not know at compile time, that spring boot fills this value.

Comment: I thought `GenerationType.IDENTITY` means that the id gets managed by the dbs. I don't know Kotlin, but in Java at least you don't have to initate this value. Also, in Java, as far as I know, the type of the Id type provided in the repository interface should match the type set in the entity, which would mean: `interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {}`. Anyhow, just some thoughts...